# Search for a match across two columns in same row VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a simple program below that allows a user to input a vehicle with its hours and expenses for a specific date. The data is recorded on a sheet called "Data". I want to ensure that there is no repeated data entered for the same vehicle type for the same date as that would be redundant data. I was using the excel "find" function to achieve similar results in other places in my program but was having difficulty doing the same here as I now need to ensure that two columns in the same row have matching text. For reference, here is how I checked for matches in other parts of the code:

```vb
            SDes = ""
            
            a = 0
        
            On Error GoTo continue
            SDes = Sheets("Vehicles").Range("Dyn_Vehicles").Find(txtName)
            
            Search = Me.txtName.Text
            Set foundcell = Worksheets("Vehicles").Columns(1).Find(Search, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
    'if exists - return record row
            If Not foundcell Is Nothing Then RecordRow = foundcell.Row
            
            
            If SDes <> "" Then
                a = a + 1
            Else
    continue:
                SDes = "0"
                a = 0
            End If
        
            If a >= 1 Then
            answer = MsgBox("Data already exists. Would you like to overwrite the previous entry?", vbCritical + vbYesNo, "Data Exists")
            
            If answer = vbYes Then

                Sheets("Vehicles").Range("Data_Start1").Offset(RecordRow - 1, 0) = expUF.txtName
                Sheets("Vehicles").Range("Data_Start1").Offset(RecordRow - 1, 1) = expUF.txtRp
                Sheets("Vehicles").Range("Data_Start1").Offset(RecordRow - 1, 2) = expUF.txtOC           
                MsgBox "Previous entry overwritten.", vbInformation, "Entry Overwritten"
            
                Exit Sub
            Else
            
                MsgBox "New entry was not added.", vbInformation, "Entry Not Added"
            
                Exit Sub
            End If
            End If
        
            If a = 0 Then
                MsgBox ("New vehicle added."), vbInformation, "Vehicle Added"
            End If
        
        
        Sheets("Vehicles").Range("Data_Start1").Offset(TargetRow, 0) = expUF.txtName        
        Sheets("Vehicles").Range("Data_Start1").Offset(TargetRow, 1) = expUF.txtRp       
        Sheets("Vehicles").Range("Data_Start1").Offset(TargetRow, 2) = expUF.txtOC        
        End If
```

userform

[image]

excel data

[image]

Comment: Before searching for a row with the matching data on to update, you can use `Application.CountIfs` to check if it exists

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to remove duplicate data consider this.  This will search the sheet, and range for any data that matches on the first two columns and remove duplicates.  You can extend the array range if you want to encompass more than your Name and Date field as your "comparing" fields.

```
Sub test()
    Worksheets("Vehicles").Range("Dyn_Vehicles").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2)
End Sub
```